# Xcode: are links in comments clickable?

Tags: xcode, hyperlink, comments, swift-playground

When a link is in a comment, Xcode makes it blue instead of gray, but is there a way for the link to actually be clickable and not simply a blue font?

Is a comment link clickable in Swift Playgrounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just hold `Command` while clicking.

[image: apple.com opens]